# wp_get_attachment_image_src returns the wrong image

Tags: media-library, images

I uploaded an image **my-image.jpg** of dimension 1280x854, after that, I went to Dashboard > Media to crop it to 854x854. (Apply changes to All Image Sizes.)

This however only change its thumbnail in Media Library, when I click the thumbnail, the popup window shows still the original image, before cropped.

In the Uploads folder, I have verified that the cropped image files are existing, with name like **my-image-e15249112352.jpg**, **my-image-e15249112352-854x617.jpg**, etc.

I tried to get the image by its id:

`wp_get_attachment_image_src(3629, 'large');`

The expected return is the cropped image, but the actual return is the original image, like I never cropped the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this : REF: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src(3629, array( 854, 854 ));
```

Hope is useful.